# WPF create Window programmatically throw on Resources

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a WPF Window that need to be Unit Tested, so I need to create an instance of it using C# code.
The Window is using some DataTemplate available in a separate dictionary.
If I run the app everything is fine, but when I create a new instance of the Window in my unit tests, using this code:

```
MainWindow mockWindow = new MainWindow();
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Test method 
[xxx] threw exception: 
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' 
Line number '48' and line position '30'. ---> 
System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'TreeViewItemTemplate'. 
Resource names are case sensitive.
```

I assume that "somehow" I need to initialize the resources before creating the view.
How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: have you tried using DynamicResource?

Comment: You mean, instead of using StaticResource? I will give it a try now

Comment: It works, I have to use DynamicResource in order to get them resolved also programmatically! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use DynamicResource instead of StaticResource.